# .Net memory self-check

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection, profiling

There is some functions for unmanaged code, e.g. `HeapWalk` etc. Can I use it for managed heap or not? If not, how can i do it manualy? I don't mean any custom util like CLR Profiling API, but something simpler: can my app load itself list of its objects in some line?

Theoreticaly, we have GC roots so i can pass through the object graph and enumerate objects. But GC have no methods or propertis, that allow an access to inner object graph. I can only call method to get total memory

```
long totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
```

but it give almost nothing.

Comment: Why? The GC has knowledge of roots and resources (such as compiled code) that your code has no knowledge of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the GC heap doesn't use any winapi functions to implement the heap, it is implemented from scratch.  The only operating system call is VirtualAlloc() to allocate the address space for a heap segment.  Querying that with VirtualQuery() is not useful, that would only show you the big chunks without being able to observe the internal structure.

The CLR does expose low-level debugging probes into the GC heap through the DAC, supported by mscordacwks.dll.  This is used most notably by the SOS debugger extension.  But an essential requirement is to avoid the Heisenberg effect, it cannot be used inside the process because that would alter what you observe.  It must only be used by *another* process, the debugger, and only when the execution of the process is completely frozen so internal data structures are stable.  Which puts the kibosh on any idea to have a program itself use the feature.

If a "self-check" is what you are after then you don't have to help, that's already done frequently.  It happens every time the garbage collector runs.  A self-check failure is reported with ExecutionEngineException.

Comment: So it's impossible due to application should be freezed. Tnx for reply